# SVProgressHUD issues in swift 3

Tags: swift, svprogresshud

Facing very rare issue in SVProgressHUD in Swift 3

[image: Error of SVProgressHUD in Swift 3]

Check the pod file i didn't do any thing wrong as mentioned on the SVProgressHUD on github.

[image: SVProgressHUD POD file]

Comment: Try using pod 'SVProgressHUD' in podfile and do a clean build.

Comment: @SahilKapoor first i tried this but not success this error i don't know why this time come, before every thing works smoothly but now don't know either in swift 3 issues or some thing other.

Comment: i also got same issuse once i removed cocoa pods and installed again sloved problem u can try

Comment: @Ramesh i remove the pod and again install it but it's not solved the problem my bad luck

Comment: That is pure Objective-C code and no Swift at all. What did you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the way you had written code is for objective-c use below code format in swift

[image]

```
import UIKit
    import SVProgressHUD

class SubViewsViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        SVProgressHUD.show()

         Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

  //With Dispatch Queue
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }


    }

    func update() {
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome. Happy to Help :)

Comment: can you tell me how to use dispatch_async with SVProgressHUD

Comment: SVProgressHUD.show()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            
        }
  
    }

Comment: this is way I use dispatch queue

Comment: Welcome @MohammadKalim :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Install Pods

pod 'SVProgressHUD'

// Import SVProgressHUD in view controller

import SVProgressHUD


// use...
```